# JBoss 7.1.1 osgi dependency jre

Tags: class, jboss, osgi

My goal is to deploy osgi bundle in JBoss 7.1.1 , and it is using IO , bufferedimage , imageio class of JRE's rt.jar.

my question is how i can dependency jre ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add the dependency. Please explain what you have tried so far and what the problem was.

Comment: i had to add rt.jar lib from jdk bin to osgi to make my function works . i have no idea how to add dependency jdk ? may you guide me?